# vsftpd - can not set PASV mode: 500 OOPS: socket

Tags: ftp, embedded-linux, vsftpd

I ported `vsftpd` on my ARM based board running under linux 3.0.8 kernel.

When I try to establish a ftp connection to the board using Filezilla (3.7.3), I get the following error:

```
    Status: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:21
    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
    Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
    Command:    USER anonymous
    Response:   331 Please specify the password.
    Command:    PASS **************
    Response:   230 Login successful.
    Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
    Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
    Status: Connected
    Status: Retrieving directory listing...
    Command:    PWD
    Response:   257 "/"
    Command:    TYPE I
    Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
    Command:    PASV
    Response:   500 OOPS: socket
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
    Error:  Connection closed by server
    Command:    PASV
    Response:   500 OOPS: socket
    Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
    Error:  Connection closed by server
```

The configuration used for my server is as follow:

```
listen=YES
max_clients=2
max_per_ip=4
# Access rights
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=NO
write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
# Security
anon_world_readable_only=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
hide_ids=YES
pasv_enable=yes
pasv_min_port=0
pasv_max_port=0
# Features
xferlog_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=NO
ascii_download_enable=NO
async_abor_enable=YES
# Performance
one_process_model=YES
idle_session_timeout=120
data_connection_timeout=300
accept_timeout=60
connect_timeout=60
anon_max_rate=50000
pam_service_name=vsftpd
port_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

There is no firewall installed in my board.

When I force the ftp connection mode to ACTIVE mode, I can connect to the server, retrieve data, upload files ...

I tried with several ftp server, but I always face the same issue.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Could be that there is some kernel module missing?

Comment: There could be a missing configuration, such as the cmds_allowed but the documentation is not really clear on what happens if you don't specify that at all.  If you built this from source, you could figure out where the "OOPS: socket" came from and user a debugger or a bunch of debug printfs to figure out what is going on there.  Trying to find a working configuration example via a web search might be worthwhile, too.

Comment: Web searching on "500 OOPS: socket" looks like it may be productive, though there may be a number of potential causes not all of which apply.